# How do I get rid of all this duplicate code?

Tags: java, code-duplication

```
    private Optional<Player> playerWithMostCards()
    {
        Player scoringPlayer = null;
        int maxCount = 0;

        for(Player p : players)
        {
            final int count = p.pile.size();

            if(count > maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = p;
                maxCount = count;
            }
            else if(count == maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(scoringPlayer);
    }

    private Optional<Player> playerWithMostSevens()
    {
        Player scoringPlayer = null;
        int maxCount = 0;

        for(Player p : players)
        {
            int count = 0;

            for(Card c : p.pile)
            {
                if(c.is(Card.Value.SEVEN))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if(count > maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = p;
                maxCount = count;
            }
            else if(count == maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(scoringPlayer);
    }

    private Optional<Player> playerWithMostSpades()
    {
        Player scoringPlayer = null;
        int maxCount = 0;

        for(Player p : players)
        {
            int count = 0;

            for(Card c : p.pile)
            {
                if(c.is(Card.Suit.SPADES))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if(count > maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = p;
                maxCount = count;
            }
            else if(count == maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(scoringPlayer);
    }
    
    private Optional<Player> playerWithSevenOfSpades()
    {
        for(Player p : players)
        {
            for(Card c : p.pile)
            {
                if(c == new Card("7S"))
                {
                    return Optional.of(p);
                }
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private void updateScores()
    {
        for(Player p : players)
        {
            p.score = p.scopas;
        }

        playerWithMostCards().ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
        playerWithMostSevens().ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
        playerWithMostSpades().ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
        playerWithSevenOfSpades().ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
    }
```

Basically, I'm making a card game (called Scopa), and when updateScores() is called, the scores of every player should be updated. Players can earn a point by having the most cards, having the most sevens, or having the seven of spades. The logic for determining who has the most cards, sevens, and spades is very similar. How can I avoid repeating the logic across these three methods? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the name of the method I came up with, but here is what I arrived at after some time. It heavily reduces the amount of code that I had and has just as much flexibility, if not more. Let me know if you can think of a better name for "playerBestMatching", and I can edit this.

Edit: "playerBestMatching" is now "playerWithMostCardsMatching"

```
    private Optional<Player> playerWithMostCardsMatching(
        final Predicate<Card> predicate)
    {
        Player scoringPlayer = null;
        int maxCount = 0;

        for(Player p : players)
        {
            final int count = (int)p.pile.stream()
                                         .filter(predicate)
                                         .count();

            if(count > maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = p;
                maxCount = count;
            }
            else if(count == maxCount)
            {
                scoringPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(scoringPlayer);
    }

    private void updateScores()
    {
        for(Player p : players)
        {
            p.score = p.scopas;
        }

        playerWithMostCardsMatching(c -> true).ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
        playerWithMostCardsMatching(c -> c.is(Card.Value.SEVEN)).ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
        playerWithMostCardsMatching(c -> c.is(Card.Suit.SPADES)).ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
        playerWithMostCardsMatching(c -> c == new Card("7S")).ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to functional programming :) Realizing that you can pass behavior as a parameter will change how you will look at problems.

Comment: A suggestion for the name: `playerWithMostCardsMatching`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That's a really good name, I had thought of it too. I'm just a bit irked by how long it is. I'll edit my solution with that anyways :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is just to make one function to calculate the scores. You're looping trough the player list 4 times and you're looping through the cards 3 times. You only need one loop for the players and one loop for the cards to check everything.

Something like this:

```
private void updateScores()
    {
        Player playerWithMostCards = null;
        Player playerWithMostSevens = null;
        Player playerWithMostSpades = null;
        int mostCards = 0;
        int mostSevens = 0;
        int mostSpades = 0;

        for(Player p : players)
        {
            // Most cards
            final int playerPileSize = p.pile.size();            

            if(playerPileSize > mostCards)
            {
              playerWithMostCards = p;
              mostCards = playerPileSize;
            }
            else if(playerPileSize == mostCards)
            {
              playerWithMostCards = null;
            }

            // NumberOfSevens and Spades
            int numberOfSevens = 0
            int numberOfSpades = 0

            for(Card c : p.pile)
            {
                if(c.is(Card.Value.SEVEN))
                {
                  numberOfSevens++;
                }

                if(c.is(Card.Suit.SPADES))
                {
                    numberOfSpades++;
                }
            }

            if (numberOfSevens > maxSevens) {
              playerWithMostSevens = p
              mostSevens = numberOfSevens              
            } else if (numberOfSevens == maxSevens) {
              playerWithMostSevens = null
            }

             if (numberOfSpades > maxSpades) {
              playerWithMostSpades = p
              mostSevens = numberOfSpades              
            } else if (numberOfSpades == maxSpades) {
              playerWithMostSpades = null
            }
        }

        playerWithMostCards.score += 1;
        playerWithMostSevens.score += 1;
        playerWithMostSpades.score += 1;      

    }
```

I haven't tested this, but this shows the rough idea. You can practice by adding the last function.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was aware of the fact that I'm looping over the player list many times. Though, I'm trying to modularize my code to some degree and keep the methods as short as possible. The method you coded here is doing a lot of things and isn't very extensible.

Comment: Yeah that's a valid point and in that case I actually like your code. Its very explicit, each function is clear. Creating 'can-do-it-all' functions with a lot of variance depending on the context e.g mostCards or mostSevens can lead to more problems down the line when you need to refactor and you have to think about multiple things instead of one concise thing (e.g. only mostCards).

Answer (score 0):

For the last two, you could make a function. I'm not familiar with the programming language that you're using (I don't even know which language it is- tag your question next time, please), but it would look something like this:

```
private Optional<Player> playerWithMostCards()
{
    Player scoringPlayer = null;
    int maxCount = 0;

    for(Player p : players)
    {
        final int count = p.pile.size();

        if(count > maxCount)
        {
            scoringPlayer = p;
            maxCount = count;
        }
        else if(count == maxCount)
        {
            scoringPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    return Optional.of(scoringPlayer);
}

private Optional<Player> playerWithMost([type] cvalue) // I don't know what the type of Card.[Value/Suit].[SEVEN/SPADES] is.
{
    Player scoringPlayer = null;
    int maxCount = 0;

    for(Player p : players)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for(Card c : p.pile)
        {
            if(c.is(cvalue))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count > maxCount)
        {
            scoringPlayer = p;
            maxCount = count;
        }
        else if(count == maxCount)
        {
            scoringPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    return Optional.of(scoringPlayer);
}
private Optional<Player> playerWithSevenOfSpades()
{
    for(Player p : players)
    {
        for(Card c : p.pile)
        {
            if(c == new Card("7S"))
            {
                return Optional.of(p);
            }
        }
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}

private void updateScores()
{
    for(Player p : players)
    {
        p.score = p.scopas;
    }

    playerWithMostCards().ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
    playerWithMost(Card.Value.SEVEN).ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
    playerWithMost(Card.Suit.SPADES).ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
    playerWithSevenOfSpades().ifPresent(p -> p.score += 1);
}
```

I'm not sure how to integrate the top one into the function.

Comment: Thank you for responding, it's Java btw. I should remember to tag my questions. Anyways your solution isn't very applicable. I cannot combine those two methods in that way because the type of the parameters is not the same. One is a Card.Suit and the other is a Card.Value. These are enums.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry I couldn't help.